# How to avoid special characters when redirecting output in bash scripts

Tags: bash

when redirecting output from a bash script to a file, I get special characters in the file. For example,

```
for file in *; do echo $file; done > output.txt
```

then if I cat output.txt

```
cat output.txt
```

I get

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
output.txt
```

but when editing the file, I see this:

```
^[[0m^[[0mfile1.txt
^[[0m^[[0mfile2.txt
^[[0m^[[0mfile3.txt
^[[0m^[[0moutput.txt
```

How do I avoid those nasty characters?

---

Solution:

I had the following line in the .bashrc:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG
```

by removing it, I solved the problem.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Post the result of `hex < output.txt`.

Comment: Those are ANSI escape sequences that set color. Are you sure you're not capturing the output of `ls` with color options set?

Comment: Do you have an alias or function named "echo"? What does this show: `type -a echo`

Comment: I do have an alias for ls which is alias ls='ls --color=auto'. I tried to disable it, but the result is the same.

Comment: Glenn, No, I don't have an alias for echo. I edited my post with the output of your command.

Answer (score 6):

These are ANSI escape codes, used for formatting text in a terminal. Rather than trying to remove them, you should prevent them from being written in the first place.

Are you sure you're getting this from the exact code you posted? If so, your files actually have these characters in your names, and you should simply rename them.

The far more common way of seeing this is having tools that output ANSI escapes sequences. This is a reproducible way of showing the same issue:

```
ls --color=always > file
```

If your posted code was an untested example, you should go through and find the tool responsible for the ANSI codes and make it stop (make especially sure you're not looping over ls output).

Here's an example of the problem you're seeing, with `touch` as stand-in for some process/script that accidentally created filenames with ANSI escapes:

```
# Reproduce the problem
$ touch $'\x1B[0m\x1B[0mfile.txt'

# Symptoms of the problem
$ ls *.txt
?[0m?[0mfile.txt

$ for f in *.txt; do echo "$f"; done
file.txt

$ for f in *.txt; do echo "$f"; done | cat -v
^[[0m^[[0mfile.txt

# Fix the problem by renaming the bad files
$ crud=$'\x1B[0m'; for f in *"$crud"*; do mv "$f" "${f//$crud/}"; done

# Now works as expected
$ ls *.txt
file.txt

$ for f in *.txt; do echo "$f"; done
file.txt

$ for f in *.txt; do echo "$f"; done | cat -v
file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that the exact code used and the exact output produced.

Comment: The files were probably created by some script with a related bug. You can rename `^[[0m^[[0mfile1.txt` to `file1.txt` with `crud=$'\x1B[0m'; for f in *"$crud"*; do mv "$f" "${f//$crud/}"; done`. See update

Comment: The problem is NOT in the files. The same output is produced in any directory. For example, I can run "for file in /var; do echo $file; done > out.txt", and then out.txt contains "^[[0m^[[0m/var". Additionally, a listing with ls shows the me files without the characters.

Comment: Can you run `bash -x yourscript` to see if you have functions overriding echo?

Comment: See my original post, I found the problem, and it is what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Run the raw ls command

/bin/ls

as

/bin/ls > your_file

and you will avoid the special characters in the output file your_file.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid those nasty characters with the ls -f option (which disables color) like so:

`for file in $(ls -f *); do echo $file; done > output.txt`

Paul

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ls` like this in the first place.

Comment: Hi chepner, can you explain why? I'm just repeating an example shown in http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html

Comment: Any filename containing whitespace will be incorrectly split into multiple words, each of which is treated as a separate value for `file`. The code in the original question is the correct method, which suggests the OP is not posting the exact code being used to generate the ANSI escape characters.

Comment: The page you linked would convince me to never recommend that that guide to anyone, let alone beginners.

Comment: ouch, those sneaky spaces! Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Paul, I get exactly the same output when using ls instead of *.

Comment: I know the original question did not mention the ```ls``` command but this was actually my problem since I have  ```--color```  as a bash alias. You ```ls -f ``` was just what I was looking for.